# netsh dhcp differs from mmc dhcp

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, netsh, mmc

While building an automated script for counting the amount of Wi-Fi users I encountered the following problem on our W2k8r2-server:

```
Netsh dhcp server scope 192.168.1.0 show clients

No of clients: 13 in scope.
```

While looking at Microsoft Management Console / DHCP Server / Address leases I only see 8 leases.

What is going on here?